# Kubernetes Ingress nodejs timeout issue

Tags: node.js, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am running my nodejs server on kubernetes cluster using Ingress. 
I am using below to prevent timeouts.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "120"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "180"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "180"
```

Still i get `502 bad gateway error`. Its not consistent, i get 502 at 7 sec, 20 sec 60 sec etc.

When i see Ingress logs, i see below errors

```
 shm_add_upstream::shm_add_node(host:port)failed while logging request

shm_add_node::ngx_slab_alloc_locked() failed: used_size[6313245], used_node[2542] while logging request, 

shm_add_server() failed while logging request
```

Is there a way to fix above issue? Is it related to any memory issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the shared memory size in use by nginx-module-vts
2. Set to more than **32M** shared memory size by default.

   `vhost_traffic_status_zone shared:vhost_traffic_status:32m`
3. If the issue still appears, increase to more than (usedSize * 2).

Example **nginx.conf**

```
http {
  vhost_traffic_status_zone;
  vhost_traffic_status_zone shared:vhost_traffic_status:32m;
}
```

Comment: Is 6313245 in kb or MB?

Comment: @Hacker **kb**. 6313245 it's in use ?

Comment: Can you help me as to how to check current value in kubernetes and how to increase it?

Comment: @Hacker either in web UI `Server main -> shared memory -> used size`  or in **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** http  block. If you didn't read it yet - https://github.com/vozlt/nginx-module-vts#to-get-status-of-traffic-zones-on-the-fly

Comment: @A_Sush - I dont have nginx.conf file. I have Only ingress configuration done. My application is nodejs server

Comment: @Hacker Are you using virtual host traffic status module?

Comment: We have been provided a cluster. I am not sure if it is using that module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191539/discussion-between-a-suh-and-hacker).